# building multiple project in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I have projects A,B in visual studio under the solution AB.
B is a static library with a simple method named "add" which is already declared with __declspec(dllexport)

and A is an application depending on B.

the build order is configured B -> A

B.lib is getting created properly but i am getting **"error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _add referenced in function _main"**

I also referenced the B.lib's directory in Additional dependencies in A's Project settings page

Please let me know where i am making the mistake....

Answer (score 0):

sry got the solution to my problem...

**C:\Documents and Settings\absasdf\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AB\Debug; added to Linker>General>Additional Library Directories**

and

**B.lib added to Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies**

Now its working fine..